# How can i print information from one main file txt or php to all content on a website

Tags: php, include

Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Okay I am looking for a way that I can use one file to edit all content on my website.

So if I am using a file in my header saying:

```
<?php include("content.php");?> 
<?php include("content.txt");?>
```

in content.php or conntent.txt you have:

```
<?php
$SayHello = "Hello, How are you I am john";
$SayNo = "No, Try this";

?>
```

in index.php you have something like this

```
<div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="span6">
                    <h4 class="total-solution-head"> print $SayHello </h4>
                    <p class="total-solution-para">print $SayNo</p>
```

I know i am doing my code wrong i would like to know the right way to do this thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run PHP code, you need to tell PHP that you're writing PHP code:

```
<?php print $SayHello ?>
```